# how i could make better this command for detect a transparent watermark?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a simple command for detect a transparent  watermark transform the watermark to black  but this command fail detect the circle but with a extra space

[image]

```
convert -noise 20x20 resultnn.png output.jpg
convert output.jpg  +dither -posterize 2 mono12.png
```

how i could do this better

this is my output

[image]

i expected something like this

[image]

what I could do

doing a crop i obtain this

```
     convert mono12.png   -fuzz 10% -fill blue +opaque  "#000000"  monod12.png 

      corde=$(convert monod12.png  -median 3x3 -format %@ info:)
     convert resultnn.png   -crop $corde +repage  resulnmonod12.png
```

[image]

this is my expected output

[image]

i need detect the circle ; I would use a command to detect it by color; But as it is a transparent watermark this is impossible

Please help me

Comment: Huh? Not sure I can see the difference between what you wanted and what you got. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: detect the circle watermark when i do my command this enclose the circle but not Fits perfectly with the circle

Comment: i uploaded a cropped image

Comment: with this command i can get the coordinate for crop the image but dont fit perfectly with the circle https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IFe5.png

Comment: i uploaded another image https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCTxw.png

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to do. I have no idea what/where the watermark is. I have no idea why you think posterisation is the way to remove it? I don't know what the extra piece is on the right.

Comment: the circle is a transparent watermark

Comment: i need detect the circle ; I would use a command to detect it by color;
But as it is a transparent watermark this is impossible

Comment: i detected another watermarks with this command but this watermark fails